# I'm new with angular.js, I just try to create a login form using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

1. All working find when I try to login first time, but second time after logout submit button not working.
2. Can We do this code shorter and better way using anguler.js Please help

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app">

    <div ng-controller="HttpGetController">     
        <div ng-hide ="logedin">
            <p>User: <input type="text" name="firstName" ng-model="firstName" required /></p>
            <p>Password: <input type="text" name="lastName" ng-model="lastName" required /></p>
            <button ng-click="SendData()">Submit</button>               
        </div>
        <div class="userDetail" ng-hide="userDetail">
                {{message.result[0].FIRST_NAME + " " + message.result[0].LAST_NAME}}    
                <div class="logout"><a href="#" title="title" ng-click='logout()'>Logout</a></div>
        </div>
        </div>      
</div>
```

Javascript (angular)

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);        
app.controller("HttpGetController", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.userDetail = true;
    if(!localStorage.getItem('logedin')){       
        $scope.SendData = function () {                 
            var creds = 'username=' + $scope.firstName + '&password=' + $scope.lastName;                                
            var config = {
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
                }
            }               
            var res = $http.post('http://api.example.com/beta/login.php', creds, config);               
            res.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {               
                if(data.success){
                    $scope.logedin = true;                      
                    $scope.message = data;
                    localStorage.setItem("logedin", angular.toJson(data));
                    $scope.userDetail = false;
                } else {
                    alert(data.description);
                }                               
            });                             
        };          
    } else {            
        $scope.logedin = true;
        $scope.message = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('logedin'));   
        $scope.userDetail = false;          
    }       
    $scope.logout = function(){         
        window.localStorage.removeItem('logedin');          
        $scope.logedin = false;
        $scope.userDetail = true;           
    }   
});
```

Comment: please note the title is the key to a question.Please avoid typos in title `angular` != `anguler`

Comment: @SagarV There's second occurance of Anguler in the title :)

Comment: @entio forgot to turn on `g` flag in my brain. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine on my side.
May be your page is getting refreshed on logout before ng-click trigger, because of `href="#"` 
Though, I am not seeing this refresh on my side, as I have not hosted the pages, you can try `href="javascript:void(0)"` in place of  `href="#"`
to stop page from refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see your function might not be defined when controller is initialized in case of a refresh after login

```
$scope.SendData = function () {                 
            var creds = 'username=' + $scope.firstName + '&password=' + $scope.lastName;                                
            var config = {
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
                }
            }               
            var res = $http.post('http://api.bhugtankaro.com/beta/login.php', creds, config);               
            res.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {               
                if(data.success){
                    $scope.logedin = true;                      
                    $scope.message = data;
                    localStorage.setItem("logedin", angular.toJson(data));
                    $scope.userDetail = false;
                } else {
                    alert(data.description);
                }                               
            });                             
        };
```

Have this function definition outside the if condition

```
if(!localStorage.getItem('logedin')){    
}
```

And then you can have if condition inside the function defintion otherwise after login if you refresh the function will not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Please avoid using href="#" on your logout button.
Please try `

`<a href="" title="title" ng-click='logout()'>Logout</a>`